# BackboneJS How to fetch specific value from API JSON file

Tags: json, backbone.js

I have a `BackboneJS` Application where I want to fetch a specific value from a JSON API.

The JSON file has this structure:

```
"data":  {
  "title": "some title",
  "startDate": "some start date",
  "endDate": "some enddate",
  "description": "description blablabla ",
  "contest_id": 10,
  }
```

I want to  fetch the "contest_id". So I have this Backbone Model:

```
CompetitionQuestion.CompetitionQuestionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return App.APIO + '/i/contest/' + this.contest_id;
    },

    defaults: {
        "data": []
    }       

});
```

This gives me `/i/contest/undefined` Why is that?? I cant do:

```
return App.APIO + '/i/contest/' + this.data.contest_id;
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using this.get('contest_id')?

Comment: @JohnP Unfortunately this didnt work :-/

Comment: The JSON structure you show on top, you store it in the CompetitionQuestionModel right? Do you store it including the `data` parent attribute or do you only set the values inside `data`? If the structure is in your model either `this.get('data').contest_id` or `this.get('contest_id')` should work. Can you confirm that both forms do not work?

Comment: Sorry, didnt really get your question but both of your suggestions do not work! :-/

Comment: Can you show the code where you populate the backbone model? The code you've posted here won't work unless you already have data in the model.

Comment: The url is used to get the data. It is not possible to construct a url from data that don't yet exist. This Model I suppose is part of a collections. Do you populate your model with data when you initialise it?

Comment: OK I fixed it myself. Actually the `this.contest_id` did work. There was an issue when fetching and populating the model.